# How to deserialize after serializing with binary DataContactSerializer?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I successfully deserialized after serializing with *default* DataContractSerializer.

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
DataContractSerializer dcSerializer = new DataContractSerializer( typeof( Library ) );
dcSerializer.WriteObject( ms, lib );
ms.Position = 0;
var returned = dcSerializer.ReadObject( ms ) as Library;
```

But if I use a binary writer and a binary reader, this code throws an exception.

```
MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream();
var binWriter = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateBinaryWriter( ms2 );
dcSerializer.WriteObject( binWriter, lib );
ms2.Position = 0;
var binReader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateBinaryReader( ms2, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max );
// throws an exception
var returned2 = dcSerializer.ReadObject( binReader ) as Library;
```

The exception message is

```
There was an error deserializing the object of type Test.Library.
Unexpected end of file.
Following elements are not closed: Pages, Book, Books, Library.
```

Here's the Library class.

```
[Serializable]
public class Library
{
    [XmlAttribute, DataMember]
    public string Name;
    [DataMember]
    public Person Owner;
    [XmlAttribute, DataMember]
    public DateTime DateEstablished;
    [DataMember]
    public List<Book> Books;
}
```

And the Book class.

```
[Serializable]
public class Book
{
    [XmlAttribute, DataMember]
    public string Title, ISBN, Author;
    [XmlAttribute, DataMember]
    public DateTime DatePublished;
    [XmlAttribute, DataMember]
    public int Pages;
    [DataMember]
    public List<string> TableOfContents;
}
```

I've setup a sample on .net fiddle. https://dotnetfiddle.net/wV8VAh

It doesn't run on the site because it lacks System.Runtime.Serialization assemblies. But if you drop it into a Visual Studio project, and add the assembly, it will run just fine. (and throw an exception!)

What have I missed?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to flush the writer and stream after doing the WriteObject:

```
binWriter.Flush()
```

Comment: Disposing the `XmlDictionaryWriter` (putting binWriter in a `using` statement) also would have solved it.